# Copy One Column value of one table into column of another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, insert

I have Product Table and Location Table in sql server 2008. Now I want to insert all the ProductId of Product Table into the ProductId column of Location Table using sql script.
And i will insert other columns value of Location table as static,But ProductId column value want to insert from Product Table using sql script.

Please Help me?

Comment: Post your table structures here. It is impossible to form the WHERE clause with the information provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your table structure, and assuming the Field1 is varchar and Field2 is int you can do this:

```
Insert Into LocationTable (productid, Field1, Field2)
Select productId, 'Field1', 10 From ProductTable
Where ....
```

Answer (score 0):

is this you are asking for ?

SELECT 'col_name_of_productid_inLocation_table-here' INTO location FROM Products

otherwise,

i think the following url may help you in this regard

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

let me know the status